# sql change month name from dutch to english

Tags: sql-server, date

The data I get from an e-mail parsing is in the format '23 juli 2016' (dutch date) and I need to put this in SQl-server. So I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO test(naam, email, telefoon, res_nummer, datum, tijd, aantal, opmerkingen)
    VALUES( 'James',
            'james@james.nl',
            '0123456789',
            '1234567890',
            '23 **juli** 2016',
            '19:00',
            '2',
            'geen')
```

Now when I run this query I get

> "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string."

So this means the date is not in a correct format. Changing it to the English format is the solution so the query:

```
INSERT INTO test(naam, email, telefoon, res_nummer, datum, tijd, aantal, opmerkingen)
    VALUES( 'James',
            'james@james.nl',
            '0123456789',
            '1234567890',
            '23 **july** 2016',
            '19:00',
            '2',
            'geen')
```

works just fine.

I just can't figure out how to change the dutch month name into the English one using SQL statements in a way the every month is converted automatically. The format of the date is always the same (dd month year).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! so simple but it works!

Comment: If e-mail parsing is NOT on SQL Server side than why not convert it to ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily change the language used before you run the insert and then change it back to w/e it should be.

Try `Set Language 'Nederlands'` before the insert to make the Dutch names acceptable.